# How to safely swap/replace a PhysicalDisk in a Parity Storage Pool

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

I have Storage Space configured with Parity resiliency that has a total of 5 SATA drives. 4 of the drives are near full capacity (90% used).

I am now getting a low capacity warning because this. I have no more SATA ports available for additional drives (and I don't want to use USB 2.0/USB 3.0), so my plan was to replace two of the existing 2 TB drives with 3 TB drives. As well as a capacity increase, the idea is the during the rebuilding/repairing the remaining 2 TB drives will hopefully be "balanced" a bit, so their usage will be below my custom set threshold of 85%.

[image: Storage Spaces configuration]

As I have parity I can survive one disk being pulled out of the space without any data loss, however I want to perform the swap properly, rather than that simulating hard disk failure by simply pull one drive out.

What steps do I need to take to perform this task? I'm aware I'd need to use PowerShell but I'm looking for specific guidance to ensure that the swap is done correctly. I'm thinking I'll also need to do this with one disk at time, otherwise I'll lose the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Retire the disk that you want to replace:

`Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName 'WDC...' -Usage Retired`

2. Repair the virtual disk and distribute the remaining data from the retired disk to the healthy disks:

`Repair-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName 'MOTHERSHIP'`

3. Finally, remove the retired disk:

`$PDToRemove = Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName 'WDC...'`

`Remove-PhysicalDisk -PhysicalDisks $PDToRemove -StoragePoolFriendlyName 'Media Storage'`

You can't use `-FriendlyName` when using `Remove-PhysicalDisk`, instead you can store the output of `Get-PhysicalDisk` in a variable and pass it to `Remove-PhysicalDisk`, PowerShell will then convert it to the correct object for you.

You may also get a warning about fault tolerance when running this command. Providing you have resiliency, this won't cause any issues.

Then add the new disk as usual.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to match similar information I found regarding Storage Spaces and PowerShell. I'll be testing this out on a production server once I've had a chance to test it on VM in the next few days. I'll mark as answer if all goes well!

Comment: Two of the 2 TB drives have the same model number. What is the best way to identify and target the right drive accordingly when using `Set-PhysicalDisk`?

Comment: Nevermind, I decided to append (Slot X) to the friendly name by cross referencing the drive serial number with which bay location it was in the server

Comment: Best way to identify? Have you tried `Get-PhysicalDisk`?

Comment: Yes. But two disks has the same FriendlyName, so I wanted to make sure it didn't tag both, so I changed them both to a unique value.

Comment: Also I've done this on a production server and it works great, with the exception of the Remove-PhysicalDisk, it has no FriendlyName parameter, so instead I stored the Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName in a variable and placed it on the command that way, which PowerShell converts into the right object

Comment: Marked as answer, with an edit made to step 3, which I hope is approved :)